# antlr4 grammar match any character question

Tags: antlr4

I think .*? can match any characters except \n, but follow can not parse '{' and '}'

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside a parser rule, the `.` matches any token, not any character. Change the rule into a lexer rule instead:

```
HeadDesc : '<?' .*? '?>';
```

And then the `.` will also match line breaks.